# Something wrong when I use jquery .click function in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, css

I am trying to change they way my cart shows. Today it is using css3 to show on hover.

I need it to display `onclick` I've tried a lot of different suggestions here on Stackoverflow but it still doesn't work. I am a amateur and hope that someone can help me understand why it is not working!

When I add `display: table;` to `.box-dropdown` it shows it the way i want it but I can't get it to do that! :(

It works perfectly on JSFiddle when i remove other elements around it. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ggoe8v6k/

The website is http://swemed.se

I tried :

```
$(".top_cart_a").click(function () {
    $('.box-dropdown.cart').css("display", "table");
});
```

And :

```
$(".top_cart_a").live('click',function() {
    $('.box-dropdown.cart').css("display", "table");
});
```

Comment: WordPress and  `$` don't play well together out of the box. Where is the rest of the JS (if any) that accompanies this?

Comment: Ok, is there another way to do this in wordpress, instead of using $ in the head tag?

There isn't any another code. I just want to start by making it open on click and take it from there but got stuck right in the beginning.

Comment: WordPress uses `jQuery` instead of `$` by default.

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: No, haven't figured it out yet. The code works in JSFiddle but not on the live site. Tried looking at the version of the applied jQuery and it is up to date. Tried different codes that I found on the internet, works on JSFiddle but still no success on live site. Also tried writing the code as you suggested but no difference :(

Comment: how are you putting the code in: Footer or separate `.js` file? Are you sure it's being enqueued correctly (if it's in a `.js` file) and is being loaded on the page?

Comment: It is inside a seperate .js file (in footer). There is another script in that file that works. So it must be loaded correctly. I've removed the password for 24 hours again so that you can view it if you like to :)

Comment: Sorry, the js file name is swemed-functions.js

Comment: you should post the relevant HTML exactly as it is on the site - and then paste that into jsFiddle. Right now it doesn't seem to be the same so debugging is tricky.

Comment: @user3199191 any of the exact HTML from the site to post here?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping javascript in a self invoking function. jQuery as an argument and `$` as a variable:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $(".top_cart_a").click(function () {
   $('.box-dropdown.cart').css("display", "table");
});

   });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JSFiddle, you forgot to include JQuery library, resulting in a `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error.

Comment: I have fixed it now, could you please have a look? :)

Comment: Yes it is working super in the JSFiddle but not on the live page. http://swemed.se/klinikinredning/rullstolar-rollatorer/hopfallbara-rullstolar/. I can't understand why :(